# How to properly add a ContentProvider into an existing app architecture?

Tags: android, architecture, android-service, android-contentprovider

I'm in the process of implementing my first ContentProvider. Since I'm quite inexperienced I wanted to check if my general design is sound.

So these are my requirements:

- The web-service providing the original data might update the data it holds once per day. I can check for such a version change.
- From the app's point of view, the data is read-only (think of weather or stocks data).
- I already have a class that can take queries from the application domain, transform them into matching HTTP requests and asynchronously return domain objects. As you might guess, this is what the app currently uses to obtain data directly from an activity.
- Now I want to do better and employ a `ContentProvider` to persist data locally.
- Once per day the app would start a `Service`, that checks the data version on the server and when needed, update the data contained in the `ContentProvider`.

The following is the design that I've come up with:
[image: ContentProvider Design]

Arrows indicate data-flow, not code-dependency.

I've noticed, I forgot to add a layer on top of the `ContentProvider` to convert Cursors to domain objects, but ignoring these details, do you think, this is a sound way of adding a `ContentProvider` to an app's architecture?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!